# N2CMS: Tilde path not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, n2cms

I am trying to use N2CMS in an existing MVC website. The problem is that when I browse the dhasboard (`http://localhost:64826/N2/`), I get some of the Menu links with Tilde.

```
e.g. This is the ink for "templates"
http://localhost:64826/N2/~/N2/Content/Templates/Default.aspx?selected=/start/&item=2
```

Here is an image of the problem: http://postimg.org/image/7xaup0idz/

Any idea how to get these links working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to download the source code and change the method "ToAbsolute(string applicationPath, string path)" in N2.Web.Url.cs.